# How do I create a string accumulator in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried looking up a previous question but nothing popped up. My professor wants us to create a program with Python that can convert Binary back to Text, by entering one byte at a time. I tried to use the following code, but my accumulator keeps failing to work. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
def main():

    length = int(input('How many characters would you like to convert with binary?'))

    accu = ''

    for i in range(length):

        binary = input('Enter some binary and I will make it into text: ')
        base = int(binary, base = 2)
        decoded = chr(base)
        print(decoded)
        decoded + str(accu)        

    print(accu)

main()
```

Comment: Could you provide us an example of input and it's repectively expected output? Also, at first glance, how do you expect see something in variable `accu` without storing anything in it? You are just initializing it with a empty string and the value of `decoded + str(accu)`  is not beeing stored anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

You have the problem because you do not save result of adding newly decoded symbols to `accu`. Change the line `decoded + str(accu)` with the line `accu += decoded`. This will allow you to save all the decoded symbols into a single string `accu`.